# Prove that ∀y(∀xP(x, y) → ∃xP(x, y)) is a tautology

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

So I'm attempting to prove the above proposition is a tautology, but am struggling to structure my argument as a logical proof.

So my current thinking is that there exist a few situations, regardless of the values of x,y

- P(x,y) is always true, in which case true => true, which is true
- P(x,y) is always false, in which case false => false, which is true
- P(x,y) is a mix of true and false, in which case there must always be an x, such that P(x,y) is true, in which case we have false => true, which is true

So I can see that the proposition is a tautology, however, I am having trouble wording this a logical proof. How would you recommend I do this?

Comment: Generally, $\forall x \in X\, P(x)$ always implies $\exists x \in X\, P(x)$, as long as the set $X$ is nonempty.

Comment: … and in the case of $X$ being empty $\forall y\in X~(\text{anything about }y)$ is *vacuously true*, so you thus only need to consider the case where the domain, $X$, is nonempty.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof needs only show that:

> Taking *any arbitrary* $y$, should every $x$ satisfies $P(x,y)$, then (because $\underline{\hspace{10ex}}$) there will be some $x$ which satisfies $P(x,y)$ .

$$\therefore\quad\forall y~(\forall x~P(x,y)\to\exists x~P(x,y))$$

Just fill in the blank.

Comment: I understand this, but I'm not really sure what the explanation should be. I mean it makes sense that if every x satisfies P(x,y) then, of course, there will be some x that satisfies P(x,y) but is there some terminology I should use to describe this or?

Comment: Maybe I should bring sets into this? Let all values of x be denoted by the set D, such that all values of D satisfy P(x,y), then a single value of x would also satisfy P(x,y) as it would be a subset of D. 

Or is this going to far?

Comment: You do not need to bring sets into this.   What inference rules do you have available to work with universal and existential quantifiers?  (For any $y$, $\forall x~P(x,y)$ entails … by rule of …., and this entails $\exists x~P(x,y)$ by rule of ….)

Comment: No inferences so far, unfortunately, (I've only just started quantifiers) hence why I am struggling to come up with a good way to write this out. One of the examples I referred to earlier used sets to prove similar a proposition using quantifiers which is why I suggested the use of them